# Copy Taxonomy Field from one item to another

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom

I use CSOM and I want to copy a taxonomy field from one list item to another. 
Can someone give me an example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**gautam**, thank you for the effort, I think I have found a bit more elegant way to do this.

```
                case "TaxonomyFieldType":
                    {
                        var txValue = value as TaxonomyFieldValue;
                        var str = txValue.Label + "|" + txValue.TermGuid;

                        destination[key] = str;

                        break;
                    }


                case "TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti":
                    {
                        var txValue = value as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
                        var values = txValue.Select(f => f);

                        var arr = values.Select(v => v.Label + "|" + v.TermGuid);
                        var str = String.Join(";", arr);

                        destination[key] = str;

                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code to Copy Taxonomy Field from one item to another